# Moq variable for creating exception using NUnit and C#

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I need to create a Unit Test Case case  for the `HttpOperationException` using Moq and nUnit.

But, I am not able to
create a moq object of the StatusCode variable in `bar` method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> foo(string a, string b,PowerBIReportIdentityType c, string d, string e, long f) 
{
    try
    {
        await _logger.LogDebugAsync("Message String");
        var r = await rep.method1(Guid.Parse(a), Guid.Parse(b), c, d, e, f);
        r.Report.ViewMode = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(editPermission) ? 0 : 1);
        await _logger.LogDebugAsync($"Get ReportEmbedToken completed for report: {reportId}");
        return Ok(r);
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return NotFound("Message string");
    }
    catch (HttpOperationException e)
    {
        await _logger.LogErrorAsync($"Error: StackTrace: {e.StackTrace}", e);
        return bar(e);
    }
}

protected ObjectResult bar(HttpOperationException x)
{
    return StatusCode((int) x.Response.StatusCode,"Error Message String");
}

public virtual ObjectResult StatusCode([ActionResultStatusCode] int statusCode, [ActionResultObjectValue] object value)
{
    return new ObjectResult(value)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode
    };
}
```

Here is what I have written up till now, but I am not able to create a moq object of StatusCode:

```
[Test]
public async Task  Test()
{
    _mockReportManager.Setup(d => d.GetReportEmbedToken(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<Guid>(),
        It.IsAny<PowerBIReportIdentityType>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<long>())).ThrowsAsync(new HttpOperationException());
    
    var result = await _controller.Get(workspaceId, reportId, _identityType, customData, reportFilter, userPersonalizedReportId);
    
    var ex = result as StatusCodeResult;
    
    Assert.AreEqual(ex, 404);
}
```

Comment: Could you share your Test Method Code, so that we could see how you have tried to moq it and what possibly is going wrong ?

Comment: I have added the test case which I have written. Can you please take a look and tell me how can I create a moq object of StatusCode

Comment: @Lily Which dependency could throw `HttpOperationException`? `rep.method1`? If so, then what is `rep`?

Comment: @PeterCsala, rep.method1 could throw the HttpOperationException. rep1 is the object of the class.

Comment: @Lily Okay, could you please share some information about *that class*? So, does the type of `rep` implements some interface, which defines the `method1`? Or is `method1` `virtual`? In order to be able to mock `method1` we need to more about the function itself and the its container class.